# Recursively list CSV of filename,dir

Tags: bash, shell, loops, csv, recursion

Pretend my root was:
`foo`

I have a folder structure of:

```
-foo
  -123
    -file.jpg
    -file2.jpg
  -456
    -file.jpg
    -file2.jpg
```

The directory could potentially be a few folders deeper.

If I had the root as such:

`ROOT=foo`

How would I go about listing every filename and their path in a CSV sort of format in a shell script?

I tried a few of the answers but I'm struggling to make it output a long string of CSV.

I'd expect something like:

```
file.jpg,123,file2.jpg,123,file.jpg,456,file2.jpg,456
```

So, I tried this:

```
# make a var for files in current folder
arr=(./*)
CSVRETURN=""
# simple loop to iterate files
for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++)); do
    #do something to each element of array
    CSVRETURN="$CSVRETURN","${arr[$i]}"
done
echo $CSVRETURN
```

It keeps adding periods to my output and I don't believe I even have the recursive portion correct. Could somebody please point me in the right direction or a doc that may help?

I've done very little with shell scripts but I'm trying :) Basically going to take this answer and export to a CSV for an entire directory and provide links for images with their dir path (relative to initial dir) for easy filtering to import to Excel.

Comment: That's not a sane output format to want to have.

Comment: Do you want to have the output in a form which is really CSV parsable? In this case, you need to take into account, that filenames can also contain a comma or a newline. I wouldn't create the CSV format from the command line manually, but use one of the many CSV libraries which are available for various programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `bash`, this can be easily done if you have `GNU find`

```
find foo -type f -printf '"%f","%h"\n' | paste -d, -s -
```

- `%f` for filename
- `%h` for leading directory path
- `paste -d, -s -` concatenates newline separated result into a comma separated single line

Or a more general solution with `BSD find` since it does not support the `-printf` option

```
find foo -type f -print | sed 's|^\(.*\)/\(.*\)|"\2","\1"|' | paste -d, -s -
```

**Output**

```
"file1.jpg","foo/123","file2.jpg","foo/123","file1.jpg","foo/456","file2.jpg","foo/456"
```

---

To generate a quick test case, you can use

```
mkdir -p foo/{123,456}
touch foo/{123,456}/file{1..2}.jpg
```

to produce a directory structure like

```
foo/
├── 123
│   ├── file1.jpg
│   └── file2.jpg
└── 456
    ├── file1.jpg
    └── file2.jpg
```

Comment: this isn't a real comma separated list.  What if the filenames themselves have comma's in them ?

Comment: @hmedia1 Good catch, in that case, probably adding a double quote around the file name and path would be a safer way to do, such as `-printf "\"%f\",\"%h\"\n"`

Comment: and what if they contain double quotes?

Comment: @perreal I agree that it would probably be safer and cleaner to use a dedicated csv parser if the filenames somehow manage to contain these special characters (comma, double quote, newline). If filenames contains double quotes `"`, I would attempt to add a `sed 's/"/""/'` into the pipeline to make the embedded double quote valid

Answer (score 0):

**Since you want:**

- No leading period
- To handle folders
- Single line CSV

You could have two conventions (based on my understanding of your example):

1. List like:

   ```
   full/folder/file  ,  full/folder/file
   ```
2. List like:

   ```
   full/folder  ,  file  ,  full/folder  ,  file
   ```

Assuming my current directory **foo** looks like this:

```
14:37:14 ツ :foo >ls -R
sublevel1        456            123

./sublevel1:
123

./sublevel1/123:
file2.jpg file.jpg

./456:
file2.jpg file.jpg

./123:
file2.jpg file.jpg
```

Then for the **first** convention:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
first=1
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' file ; do 
    if [ "$first" == "1" ]; then 
        filestr="\"$(cut -f2- -d'/' <<< "${file}")\""
        unset first
   else 
        filestr=",\"$(cut -f2- -d'/' <<< "${file}")\""  
        fi
   printf "%s" "$filestr"
done
```

This would give you the following result:

```
"sublevel1/123/file.jpg","sublevel1/123/file2.jpg","456/file.jpg","456/file2.jpg","123/file.jpg","123/file2.jpg"
```

If you changed the `-print0` to `-printf "%h\0%f\0"`, then you'd get an output like the second convention above:

```
"sublevel1/123","file.jpg","sublevel1/123","file2.jpg","456","file.jpg","456","file2.jpg","123","file.jpg","123","file2.jpg"
```

**Notes:**

- The **null** (\0 , -print0) handling makes this a bit more reliable to handle strange file names, maybe even ones with embedded newlines.
- The `printf "%s"` format is fairly resilient in it's handling of names also when the string is passed to the program properly
- The `if` block is just to ensure a comma is not prefixed to the very first file
- The inefficiency of a "while" loop shouldn't be noticeable for any conceivable use you could have for wanting a single string csv list like this.
- I added **sublevel1** to demonstrate multiple folder levels.

For more robust applications, consider serialized JSON, or some other data representation format where processing of lists can be handled in a more complete manner.